# How to make SQL query from XSL Document?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xml, xslt

How to make the SQL query from XSLT document. Suggest me something how to retrieve this in SQL query. How the view shows I am not understanding. How to select from SQL query.
Here is the code, Which is giving errors.

Dataset Xsl Format:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:i18n="http://toolkit.sf.net/i18n/messages" xmlns:ddi="http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/DDI" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:outline="http://worldbank.org/toolkit/cdrom/outline" exclude-result-prefixes="ddi outline">
    <xsl:include href="gettext.xslt"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <!--file id -->
    <xsl:param name="file" select="'F5'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
        <div id="variable-list">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//ddi:codeBook/ddi:fileDscr[@ID=$file]"/>
        <h2><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Variables</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></h2>
        <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;border:1px solid silver;" cellpadding="2" class="table-variable-list">
            <tr class="var-th">
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">ID</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Name</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Label</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Type</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Format</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Question</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//ddi:codeBook/ddi:dataDscr/ddi:var[@files=$file]"/>
        </table>
        </div>    
        </xsl:template> 

        <xsl:template match="ddi:var">
        <xsl:variable name="class">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="'row-color1'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'row-color2'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="id" select="@ID"/>
                <xsl:variable name="link">#<xsl:value-of select="@files"/><xsl:value-of select="$id"/></xsl:variable>
        <tr valign="top" class="{$class}" style="cursor:pointer"  id="{$id}" >          
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ddi:labl"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@intrvl"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ddi:varFormat/@type"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ddi:qstn/ddi:qstnLit"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:template>
       <!-- 4.3 FILE -->
<xsl:template match="ddi:fileDscr">
    <xsl:variable name="file" select="@ID"/>
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(ddi:fileTxt/ddi:fileName,'.NSDstat')"/></h2>
    <table class="datafile-info" cellpadding="4" >
        <tr valign="top">
            <td style="width:100px"><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Content</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td>
                    <div style="width:100%;height:80px; overflow:auto;border:1px solid silver;background-color:none;">
                        <div style="padding:5px;">
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ddi:fileTxt/ddi:fileCont)"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Cases</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ddi:fileTxt/ddi:dimensns/ddi:caseQnty"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Variable(s)</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ddi:fileTxt/ddi:dimensns/ddi:varQnty"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Structure</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Type</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template>: <xsl:value-of select="ddi:fileTxt/ddi:fileStrc/@type"/><br/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Keys</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template>: 
                    <xsl:call-template name="getVariableById"><xsl:with-param name="str"><xsl:value-of select="ddi:fileTxt/ddi:fileStrc/ddi:recGrp/@keyvar"/></xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Version</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ddi:fileTxt/ddi:verStmt/ddi:version"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Producer</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ddi:fileTxt/ddi:filePlac"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td><xsl:call-template name="gettext"><xsl:with-param name="msg">Missing Data</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template></td>
            <td>    <div style="width:100%;height:80px; overflow:auto;border:1px solid silver;background-color:white;">
                        <div style="padding:5px;">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ddi:fileTxt/ddi:dataMsng"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</xsl:template> 
<!-- FileRef -->
<xsl:template name="fileRef">
    <xsl:param name="fileId"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/ddi:codeBook/ddi:fileDscr[@ID=$fileId]/ddi:fileTxt/ddi:fileName"/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Filename -->
<xsl:template match="ddi:fileName">
    <!-- this template removes the .NSDstat extension -->
    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=" contains( $filename , '.NSDstat' )">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($filename,1,string-length($filename)-8)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$filename"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="getVariableById">
<xsl:param name="str"/>
<xsl:variable name="delimeter" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($str,$delimeter)">
            <xsl:variable name="varid"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str,$delimeter)"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="var" select="//ddi:codeBook/ddi:dataDscr/ddi:var[@ID=$varid]"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$var/@name"/>(<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($var/ddi:labl)"/>), 
        <xsl:call-template name="getVariableById"> 
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring-after($str,$delimeter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimeter" select="$delimeter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="var" select="//ddi:codeBook/ddi:dataDscr/ddi:var[@ID=$str]"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$var/@name"/>(<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($var/ddi:labl)"/>)
      </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make any sense...

Comment: This the data how they are select from database I don't Know.How it works and stored data in which table.i can't understood.please the xslt he is using $delimeter in the select xslt document please find out ..

Comment: XSLT is used to *translate* XML from one format into another. Nobody will be able to answer your question with the information given... How should we know, where this data comes from? How it was called? What this XSLT is supposed to do? How did the input look like? What is your actual problem? Error? Wrong output? Please use the edit option and re-do this question!

Comment: K k  i can re-do the question tkq...i can edit and format it.

Comment: @vallavan I think the problem is partly that you are having difficulty writing clear English, and partly that you are assuming we know things about your application that we don't know. If you are trying to access a SQL database from your XSLT stylesheet, then there is no standard way of doing it: you will have to do it via vendor extension functions, or adopt a completely different approach.

Comment: K K ..but the view is taking this xslt format and its showing view but it works properly,how they bulit sql query in between the tags i do not known please suggest something

Comment: @vallavan, your XSLT is including this `<xsl:include href="gettext.xslt"/>` What is this?

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in comment, your question is absolutely unclear... This answer is a blind shot, using my magic glass bulb... And some research...

Your style-sheet retrieves something here:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//ddi:codeBook/ddi:fileDscr[@ID=$file]"/>
```

The namespace `ddi:` is declared on top with

```
xmlns:ddi="http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/DDI"
```

Just follow this link and you get to a platform called **Document, Discover and Interoperate**, which is offering a public access to datas of surveys, documents and so on. I did not dive deeper, but this seems to be a public source to load data, which is - quite probably - delivered in XML-format.

As said: I did not dive deeper... Might be this is nonsense and DDI is just a common format / interface to describe this kind of data in an interchangeable format. In this case, the answer could be the included file from here `<xsl:include href="gettext.xslt"/>`...

Your stylesheet - at least I think so - does not call any data from any classical RDBMS, but gets an XML from somewhere and **transforms** this to an `HTML`-table. This is displayed to the user within a Web-Page. Your application is probably passing the needed data as parameter `$file`.

[Read the *getting started* section for DDI here](http://www.ddialliance.org/training/getting-started)

My magic glass bulb needs new batteries now...